# @query annotation in Spring data elastic search to restrict fields

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, annotations

I have to restrict the fields at source level using _source property.

```
GET /analysis/_search?size=5
{  "_source": ["Job.jobdate"],
  "query": {"query_string": {
          "query": "(Job.state:\"PA\") "
        }

}}
```

I have to convert the above query into  @Query anotation that we use in Spring data elastic search.

Below is an example for @query annotation. But I need the similar way to achieve above query.

```
 @Query(" {\"bool\": { \"must\": [{ \"match\": {\"state\":\"08/02/2015\"}}]    }  }")
        Iterable<Feeds> findByClient(String state;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, i.e. you need to properly escape the backslash and the double quotes:

```
@Query("{\"query_string\": { \"query\": \"(Job.state:\\\"PA\\\")\"}")
```

Comment: But I need to restrict fields obtained from source as a search result. "_source": ["Job.jobdate"]. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Ok, that doesn't go into the `@Query` annotation, which only takes the `query` part of an ES request. I'd say it's up to your Java method to only return the fields you need.